# Cannot use $this->uri->segment(); in WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql, pagination, where-clause

I have a simple query but I am trying to use $this->uri->segment(); in WHERE clause
I could not get it working.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

In my controller I have:

```
public function profile()
        {

            $var = (int) $this->uri->segment(3);
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE id = $var;');
            $data['name'] = '';
            $data['section'] = "Profile";
            $data['query'] = $query;

             $this->load->view('view1', $data);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP won't evaluate variables inside string literals (' ').

Change

```
'SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE id = $var;'
```

to

```
"SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE id = $var;"
```

Comment: Great. You bet. Don't forget to hit the accepted button.